# Checking post data of a checkbox

Tags: php

I have a checkbox that I'm looking to update a contacts details with. At the moment it's not updating the contact in Send in Blue... I don't think that's the problem though.

There's 3 issues I'm not sure I'm doing correctly:

1. Checking if the data has been sent.
2. Checking the field data that already uses square brackets.
3. Checking to see if the checkbox is checked or not.

Here's my php:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

  global $SendInBlue;

  if(isset($_POST['data[newsletter_sub]']) == "on") {

    $data_in['ONETIME_NEWSLETTER'] = true;
    $data_in['PROMOS'] = true;
    $data_in['SUB_NEWSLETTER'] = true;

  } else {

    $data_in['ONETIME_NEWSLETTER'] = false;
    $data_in['PROMOS'] = false;
    $data_in['SUB_NEWSLETTER'] = false;

  }

  // Update SiB contact
  $data = array(
    'attributes'=> $data_in
  );
  try {
  $updateContact = new \SendinBlue\Client\Model\UpdateContact($data);

      $result = $SendInBlue->updateContact($email, $updateContact);
      return true;

  } catch (Exception $e) {
  }

}
?>
```

Here's some of the form with one checkbox:

```
<form method="POST" class="" id="communication_preferences" action="/event" name="communication_preferences">
  <input type="checkbox" name="data[newsletter_sub]" id="newsletter_sub" <?php if($newsletter_sub == 'yes'){ echo 'checked';}?>>
  <button class="button button--pink button--uppercase text--three js-profile-item-submit landmark ">
      Save Changes
  </button>
</form>
```

The page just reloads when you submit the form.

Comment: Can you add the HTML?

Comment: `isset($_POST['data']['newsletter_sub]')`

Comment: **Also remember** if a checkbox is not checked it is not sent from the browser to the PHP script.

Comment: **Also** `isset()` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` so this test wont work as you think `if(isset($_POST['data']['newsletter_sub]')) == "on") {`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with checkboxes is that they do not appear in the $_POST when not checked.

Your receiving script can simple do this:

```
$bMyCheckOn = isset($_POST["someCheckBoxName"]); // true/false
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that `if (!empty($_POST['newsletter_sub'])) {` matches your input.
Here, i rewrote your entire script:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {

    global $SendInBlue;

    $data_in = [];

    foreach(['ONETIME_NEWSLETTER', 'PROMOS', 'SUB_NEWSLETTER'] as $data) {
        if (!empty($_POST['newsletter_sub'])) { //Checkbox set?
            $data_in[$data] = true;
        } else {
            $data_in[$data] = false;
        }
    }

    $data = ['attributes' => $data_in];

    $attempt = new \SendinBlue\Client\Model\UpdateContact($data);
    $result = $SendInBlue->updateContact($email, $attempt) ? true : false;

    print_r($result);

} else {

    echo 'Form not submitted.';

}

?>

<form method="POST" id="communication_preferences" action="">

    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter_sub" id="newsletter_sub" <?=($newsletter_sub == 'yes' ? 'checked' : '')?>>

    <button type="submit" class="button button--pink button--uppercase text--three js-profile-item-submit landmark" name="submit" value="submit">
        Save changes
    </button>

</form>
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and add the HTML so i know what i'm working with?

Comment: Cool, i'll update shortly, please add the full form, i need to see if you set everything properly.

Comment: @Rob What i noticed is you put /action in class, did you mean to put that in action=""? If so, is that where the PHP file is? I updated my answer - just place it above your HTML for now so we know if it works. Also, be sure to update the 2nd line into your submit button's name.

Comment: @Rob I updated my answer too, check the latest version after you read this.